# Can I access the Google Maps API inside of Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-maps-api-3, cross-domain

I want to query the Google Maps API as such: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

The contents of their `crossdomain.xml` file, [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml), are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm not very experienced with ActionScript, but I believe that, since they're missing the `allow-access-from` directive, there is nothing I can do.

I can't use `ExternalInterface`, so using JSONP in Javascript is out of the question.

Is there any way I can get around this?

**NOTE:** I can't use the Google Maps API for Flash since [they're not issuing new API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup).

Comment: have you looked at the (depreciated as of september 2011) Google Maps API for Flash?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I have, but I can't get an API key. «New keys are no longer available for the Maps API for Flash.», they say here: https://developers.google.com/maps/signup

Comment: @Júlio Santos in an Adobe Air app you can load and display html content with StageWebView and HTMLLoader. With that maybe you can display a google map in your application.

Comment: i don't believe there is another way.  i'm curious why you can't use ExternalInterface?

Comment: `allowScriptAccess` will be set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps from "INSIDE" Flash IDE, without API key. Try downloading their examples and run them on flash.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see how that would be useful.

Comment: Ya.. i for production it's useless. You may however try an alternate via yahoo. http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/flash/jsGettingStarted.html

Comment: Their API seems to require `ExternalInterface`. Plus, it doesn't offer a geocoding service, which is what I'm after. But thanks.